# aws Cognito UI Customizations not updating in react natvie app

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I was trying to add a logo to my Amazon Cognito UI, in the next image you can see I uploaded the picture..

[image]

I did save the image on this setting and I restarted my expo server to see the changes but still the same UI with no logo.. :(

[image]

Do someone knows what I am doing wrong? or if I missed some step?

Thanks people!